# Wordpress fixed menu only on desktop

Tags: wordpress

I have this css

```
.site-header {
position : fixed;
top : 0;
width:100%; 
}
```

This makes the menu fixed on all devices. 
How can i disable this on mobilephones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this, It will only reflect on devices having a width more than 600px.

```
@media (min-width:600px) {
.site-header {
    position : fixed;
    top : 0;
    width:100%;
    }
}
```